# Issue adding values received from fgetc?

Tags: c

I have written a function that is meant to read any integers from a input file, find the sum of those numbers, and find the total amount of numbers(which I got working). Here it is:

```
int total = 0;
int ncount = 0; 
int cse;
do
{
    cse = fgetc(infp);
    if(cse <= '9' && cse >= '0')
    {
        total += cse;
        ncount++;
    }
}while(cse != EOF);

fprintf(outp,"Number of numbers is %d\n", ncount);
fprintf(outp, "Total is %c\n", total);
```

If i put in 78345 which should equal total = 27; I get total = 267. Similarly if I just print the fgetc values i get numbers like 53 54 57 etc. However, when I print them using %c I get 78345. How can I use this logic to add these values as sum? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(cse <= '9' && cse >= '0')` any reason not just using `isdigit`? Or - at least restructure to make clearer what you mean? And you do not count _integers_ but _digits_.

Comment: `fprintf(outp, "Total is %c\n", total);` should be with `%d`

Comment: You're using `%c` instead of `%d` to print your total.

Comment: fgetc gives you the ascii code, not the actual integers.  you could change code line from  total += cse; to total += cse - '0';

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake it is percent d in my program. Also I will update with isdigit but that shouldn't affect total being wrong correct?

Comment: Yes the cse - '0' worked, it is now printing 27. Thank you all for your help!! How do I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: @McQueen you got three correct answers. Choose the one suits you best, explains well, and click the checkmark. Also, upvote if you see the answer is correct ;-)

Comment: You might want to consider what happens if the input file is empty.  The first `fgetc` returns EOF and then you end up doing arithmetic and comparisons on EOF instead of a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetc` returns a single character code which is not equivalent to the characters numeric value. In your code you are comparing and adding character code values.

You need to convert the character code to an integer with something like:

```
 int num = cse - '0';
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things. First, you're adding the character ASCII value, not what the character represents:

```
total += cse;
```

You may want to subtract the value of character zero from that, as a barely simple conversion:

```
total += cse - '0';
```

Then, second, you're printing a character value:

```
fprintf(outp, "Total is %c\n", total);
```

Use an integer formatter like `%d`.

Comment: Glad to help @McQueen and welcome to StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- `total += cse;` should be `total += ( cse - '0' );`
- `fprintf(outp, "Total is %c\n", total);` should be `fprintf(outp, "Total is %d\n", total);`

Comment: These resolved both my issues, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

your reading characters, and treating them as numbers.

Well, '0' is the character, which has the ascii value of 48.

But what you really seem to want is to use the number 0 .

The proper way to convert is

```
int total = 0; 
int cse; 

while( cse = fgetc( stdin ) && EOF != cse) 
{ 
    total += (cse - '0'); 
}
```